# Delay validation until user tabs out of all inputs in an input group

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

My form has a group of three checkboxes. The user must select at least one of the three options:

```
<form id="myform" class="validated-form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div id="fname" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label>
      a
      <input type="checkbox" value="a" name="fname"/>
    </label>
    <label>
      b
      <input type="checkbox" value="b" name="fname"/>
    </label>
    <label>
      c
      <input type="checkbox" value="c" name="fname"/>
    </label>  
  </div>
</form>
```

I am using the following `onfocusout` callback to validate the checkbox group:

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
  
  if($(element).prop('type') == 'checkbox') {
        this.element(element);
      }

  }
```

**See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/3s7zme1r/7/).**

---

**The problem:** When the user tabs through the options, I would like the validator to wait until they have tabbed out of the group completely (i.e. when all three of the checkboxes have lost focus) before validating it.

---

My first attempt was to modify the if-statement in the callback above to include a condition that selects all elements within the group that have focus and then checks that the length of the resulting object array is 0, like so:

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
  
   if($(element).prop('type') == 'checkbox' && $(element).closest('.btn-group').find('label:focus').length == 0) {
        this.element(element);
      }
  }
```

But since there is a lag between the time that one element loses focus and another one receives it, the above doesn't work. I think this is due to the callback firing as soon as the input being validated loses focus and *before* the new element gains focus. At this time, no elements are in focus, so the if-statement condition always evaluates to `true`. For the same reason, I am unable to detect which element the focus has shifted *to* (so I can't check if the newly focused element is part of the checkbox group).

So my next attempt was to use `setTimeout`:

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    if($(element).prop('type') == 'checkbox' && $(element).closest('.btn-group').find('label:focus').length == 0) {
        this.element(element);
      }
  }, 1);
  }
```

This seems to switch off validation *completely* - tabbing from one checkbox to another doesn't trigger validation but neither does tabbing out of the checkbox group completely. Have I used it incorrectly? (In the Fiddle, it seems to have no effect.)

**Is there a better solution to this problem or am I trying to solve the wrong problem?**

**Note:** I can't use the `onclick` callback because it isn't compatible with the widget I'm using in my actual form. I prefer the feel of `onfocusout` over `onclick` anyway since it's more consistent with the Validate plugin's default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I used `event.relatedTarget` to identify which element received focus and modified the if-statement to trigger validation only if the name of the `relatedTarget` doesn't match that of the checkbox that lost focus:

```
onfocusout: function(element, event) {
  
    if($(element).prop('type') == 'checkbox' && $(event.relatedTarget).attr('name') != $(element).attr('name')) {
          $(element).valid();
        }
    
  }
```

**See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/816e2sdm/2/).**

Not sure if there are any caveats to this approach and would like to leave the post open in case someone has a better solution.